# How to check this statements about the inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I need help with this problem:

> Determine which of the following statements are true or false, justify your answer. If $x$ and $y$ are vectors on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then whe have:
>
> 1. $x\cdot y=0$ if and only if $\| x+y\|=\| x-y\|$.
> 2. $x\cdot y=0$ if and only if $\| x+y\|^2=\| x\|^2+\| y\|^2$.
> 3. $x\cdot y=0$ if and only if $\| x+cy\|\geq\| x\|$ for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$.
> 4. $(x+y)\cdot(x-y)=0$ if and only if $\| x\|=\| y\|$

I tried the first one first by assuming that $\| x+y\|=\| x-y\|$, then I rewrote the dot product as $$x^\mathrm{T} y=0=\begin{bmatrix} x_1&\cdots&x_n \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 
y_1\\ \vdots \\y_n \end{bmatrix}=x_1y_1+x_2y_2+\cdots+x_ny_n=0,$$ after that I don't know what to do. The same happens when I triedo to do the other way, can you please help me?

Comment: Do you know what the dot product represents geometrically?

Comment: I think it is the length, right?

Comment: Not quite. The dot product $a\cdot b$ of two Euclidean vectors $a,b \in \mathbb R^n$ is the length of the projection of $a$ onto $b$, scaled by the length of $b$. This gives rise to the formula $a \cdot b = \|a\| \|b\| \cos \theta$. With this in mind, can you visualize/plot the geometric meanings of the statements in your question?

Comment: No dot product of $a$ and $b$ is $0$ means $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal. Norm represents the length.

Comment: I think that, for example, the first means that $x\cdot y=0$, which means that the proyection of $x$ onto $y$ is $0$, then the distance of $x+y$ is the same as the distance $x-y$, right? I'm still kind of confused with the geometric view.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\|x+y\|^2 = \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+2\ x \cdot y.$

So all the options are correct.

For the third one observe that

> $$\|x+cy\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + |c|^2 \|y\|^2 + 2c\ x \cdot y.$$

Since $x \cdot y = 0$ we have

> $$\|x+cy\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + |c| \|y\|^2 \geq \|x\|^2$$ since $|c|^2\|x\|^2 \geq 0.$

So by taking positive square root in both sides of the above inequality we have

> $$\|x+cy\| \geq \|x\|.$$

For the fourth one observe that

> $$(x+y) \cdot (x-y) = \|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2.$$

So if $(x+y) \cdot (x-y) = 0$ then we have

> $$\|x\|^2 = \|y\|^2.$$

Taking the positive square root in both the sides we have

> $$\|x\|=\|y\|.$$

**Note** $:$ Try to do these things on your own without seeing the spoilers. Otherwise you cannot able to learn mathematics.

Comment: And since I'm assuming that $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal, $2x\cdot y=0$ right?

Comment: Exactly it is @davidllerenav.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think I have done the first two correctly, but how do I do the third and fourth one?

Comment: @davidllerenav The fourth one is not that scary. Try writing out and simplifying both sides independently.

Comment: I think I did it, but I still don't know how to do the third one. Can you help me with that one?

Comment: I have added a detailed answer above. Please take a look at it @davidllerenav.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 The third one (like the rest) is biconditional. The reverse implication is trickier.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I already did the fourth one, so with your answer I was able to check if I was right.

Comment: @TheoBendit Why is the reverse implication trickier?

Comment: @davidllerenav It's less mechanical. You have this inequality that holds for all $c$, and as part of the proof, you need to come up with a suitable $c$ to substitute in, so that the conclusion that $x \cdot y = 0$ falls out. It takes some decent geometric intuition to be able to get this yourself. If you want to try, try drawing a vector $x$, and a line through $x$ that is not perpendicular to the vector $x$ (the vector $y$ is parallel to this line). See if you can find the point on this line that the point $0$ is closest to, using the projection formula.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment under Dbchatto67's answer, here's the picture I'm picturing:

[image]

The light blue line is the line generated by $x + cy$ as $c$ ranges over $\Bbb{R}$. The inequality $\|x + cy\| \ge \|x\|$ says that $x + 0y$ is the point along the line closest to the origin $0$. As you can see in this picture, this is not the case (nor is $x$ and $y$ perpendicular), as the point marked $x + cy$ is closer to $0$ than $x$. As I recommended in my comment, we should find this closest point, using projections.

We should start by projecting the line segment between $0$ and $x$ onto the light blue line. One end of this projection should be $x$, and the other is the point we want (marked $x + cy$). We take the vector from $x$ to $0$ (which is $-x$) and project it onto the vector $y$, which defines the direction of the line. That is, we compute:
$$\operatorname{proj}_y(-x) = \frac{(-x) \cdot y}{\|y\|^2} y = -\frac{x \cdot y}{\|y\|^2} y.$$
Adding this vector to $x$ will produce the point we want, marked $x + cy$:
$$x - \frac{x \cdot y}{\|y\|^2} y,$$
which is of the desired form.

Basically, what I'm saying is that the most troublesome value of $c$ ought to be $c = -\frac{x \cdot y}{\|y\|^2}$. Let's try applying the inequality $\|x + cy\| \ge \|x\|$ with this particular value of $c$. I'm hoping the results are interesting!

We have
\begin{align*}
\|x\|^2 &\le \left\|x - \frac{x \cdot y}{\|y\|^2} y\right\|^2 \\
&= \|x\|^2 + \left\|\frac{x \cdot y}{\|y\|^2} y\right\|^2 - 2 x \cdot \left( \frac{x \cdot y}{\|y\|^2} y \right) \\
&= \|x\|^2 + \frac{(x \cdot y)^2}{\|y\|^4}\|y\|^2 - 2 \frac{x \cdot y}{\|y\|^2} x \cdot y \\
&= \|x\|^2 + \frac{(x \cdot y)^2}{\|y\|^2} - 2 \frac{(x \cdot y)^2}{\|y\|^2} \\
&= \|x\|^2 - \frac{(x \cdot y)^2}{\|y\|^2},
\end{align*}
and hence, cancelling $\|x\|^2$ from both sides,
$$\frac{(x \cdot y)^2}{\|y\|^2} \le 0 \implies (x \cdot y)^2 \le 0$$
But, $(x \cdot y)^2$ is a square number, and must be at least $0$. Thus, $x \cdot y = 0$.